# SpringSecurity external ProviderManager

Tags: spring-security

I'm creating authentication service in Spring.

In my authentication i need to connect to external webserwice, sending login and password, to check if user exist in another system.

The way i want to do it is creating external ProviderManarer.

My `spring-security.xml` file is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">


    <security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
    <security:http authentication-manager-ref="userAuthManager" disable-url-rewriting="true" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/adminPanel/" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/adminPanem/**" access="hasAnyRole('USER_ROLE', 'ADMIN_ROLE')"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/adminPanel" default-target-url="/adminPanel/panel"
                authentication-failure-url="/adminPanel"/>
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/adminPanel"/>
    </security:http>

    <bean id="userAuth" class="org.myapp.app.backEnd.auth.UserAuthentication"/>

    <beans:bean id="userAuthManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <beans:property name="providers">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref local="userAuth"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


</beans>
```

And my Testing Authentication Provider is:

```
public class UserAuthentication implements  AuthenticationProvider{


     @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

            System.out.println(" test " );

            System.out.println(authentication.getCredentials().toString());

            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN_ROLE"));

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("test", authentication.getCredentials(), authorities);  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
            return false;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }
```

But, there is a problem - my configurations doesn't invoke `public Authentication authenticate` method.

There is no output.

**Additionally**

I saw that in Spring 3.2 in:

```
<beans:bean id="userAuthManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref local="userAuth"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

The:

```
<beans:property name="providers"> is depricated.
```

Do you know how to configure it properly in Spring 3.2 ?

How to create correct configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`<authentication-manager>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-authentication-manager) tag like described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-auth-providers):

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="userAuthManager">
  <security:authentication-provider ref="userAuth" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: do i need to add 'alias' ?

Comment: OK, i've chenged xml file. I've added <security:authentication-manager alias="userAuthManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="userAuth"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>. But it doesn't invoke authenticate method.

Comment: Can you turn the [debug](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-debug) on (add `<debug />` to your config, try to login and post the output as edit in your post)?

Comment: OK, i found, that spring goes to 'supports' method not to 'authenticate' in my AuthenticationProvider . How to invoke, that spring will run 'authenticate' method ?

Comment: Ah, didn't catch that - just `return true` instead.